# cannot access $scope variable out side a function

Tags: arrays, angularjs, scope

I have a variable defined in a controller:

```
app.controller('myController',['$scope','ajaxCall',function($scope,ajaxCall){
  $scope.interviewer = {};
  ajaxCall.get(/* A url */).then(function(response){
    $scope.interviewer = response.data;
    console.log($scope.interviewer);
});
console.log($scope.interviewer);
```

ajaxCall is a custom service which is used to make ajax calls. Inner console is working fine(i.e. it is showing the complete data) but the outer console is printing an empty object.Why?

Answer (score 2):

Because the first *A* in *AJAX* means "Asynchronous".

The function passed to `then()` is executed *asynchronously*, a long time after the last `console.log()` line. It's executed once the response to the asynchronous HTTP request comes back from the server.

If it was synchronous, we wouldn't bother with promises and callback functions. We would just do

```
var response = ajaxCall.get(url);
```

But that isn't possible, so we do

```
ajaxCall.get(/* A url */).then(function(response){
```

which means: please send this request, and when the response is available, then call this function. I'll do plenty of other things in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet. I knew this concept but couldn't think of it being the reason.But I have to use the data in most part of my controller, so how to do that I don't want to write a lot of code inside the then() function.

Comment: Declaure a function `function init(response) { ... }`, and use `ajaxCall.get(url).then(init);`